# WSO2 as SCA: will it be possible?

Tags: osgi, soa, wso2, sca, soa-suite

hello again, WSO2 community.

My last question about your architecture for my research is not a technical question, but a future-oriented one instead.

I was thinking about the OSGi approach the Suite has, that is one of the most interesting abstract things about SOA in general and WSO2 in particular I have found. An OSGi is sure a puzzling puzzle.

Thinking about pieces connected together reminded me about Service Component Architecture: a mean to see all the pieces as a whole easier.

Well, my question, son of my thoughts, is: "**Why not to enable SCA for WSO2, when all the pieces have Carbon as a common denominator?**" Carbon seems to be a nice candidate to be SCA.

The architecture could have only one instance of Carbon underneath, and WSO2 components above. The user should be able to interact with Carbon through only one interface and see all the pieces and their installed feature.

Is it possible? If it's not, why?

I hope I've been of some use through all the way here, and I thank you for having accompanied me to the end of my journey!

I hope there will occasions to collaborate or simply sharing ideas again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is conceptually similar to what it does with OSGi and Endpoint References in Carbon App model. Possibly can look at SCA Assembly as an alternative wiring model.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will take this point of view into consideration :)

Comment: Have I understood this correctly, that OSGi in Carbon gives you everything that SCA does so there is no real benefit in using SCA (tuscany) in WSO2?